# How to save, export, or convert an Android XML Drawable as a PNG image file?

Tags: android, gradient, xml-drawable

I have a gradient I really like but I created it using XML drawable:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#DD181C18"
    android:endColor="#809C7D5A"
    android:angle="90"/>
```

What would be an easy way to create this to a png or something similar?

**What I'm really looking for is:** 
a tool that can and instructions using that tool to make gradients using an `#aarrggbb` format as it's input alpha/color (90 degree angle, angles in general, would be a plus).

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: D'oh! I totally just realized **ImageMagick** should be able to do this. I will post the code that is my answer shortly, unless someone wants to beat me to it and receive the whole bounty!

Comment: show it in empty layout and use image snapshot from eclipse feature or run on device and follow the same process to get high res image

Comment: Unless, I'm missing something...this also wouldn't preserve the transparency.

Comment: what about posting the code? :)

Comment: @bluszcz what code are you referring to?

Comment: @TryTryAgain Ach, sorry - I didnt notice your answer on the bottom of the page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end it was a one liner using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)!

I can't believe I didn't think to use ImageMagick before, Duh!!!

```
convert -size 480x84 gradient:'rgba(156, 125, 90, 0.52)'-'rgba(24, 28, 24, 0.86)' tmp.png
```

For reference, I used this to create a .png image file using my Android XML drawable ##AARRGGBB values. ImageMagick FTW!!!

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: how do I do that

Answer (score 3):

Use a program like photoshop or paint.Net - they both have gradient tools and should let you set the colours in the same format as you have there.

Comment: I only have access to free and OSS and OS. I haven't found out a way to achieve this with GIMP. Again, the gradient isn't the problem, rather, preserving the transparency with the gradient is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Paint.Net is free and preserves transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
try {
    item.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = item.getDrawingCache();
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here `item` is the view/view group that I want to render.

I actually use the same fragment (minus the file write) for some on screen rendering and it seems preserve transparency.

**Note About Colors:**

Colors can be specified in android using hexadecimal values. A byte (8 bits) are available for each color value in the pattern `ARGB` (total 32 bits). `A` stands for `Alpha`, `R` stands for `Red`, `G` for `Green` and `B` for `Blue`. Each component can have values between (0, 255). Note that:

```
decimal 0   = hex 0x00
decimal 255 = hex 0xFF
```

So if you wanted a white color with opaque 'Alpha`(no transparency) you would use`#FFFFFFFF`. For Black`#FF000000`. For Grey`#FF808080`.`80`is hex value of decimal 128 and gives you half of full intensity white. so`80` gives you median Grey.

Use Hexadecimal arithmetic to get values of your decimal colors.

AFAIK, Angle for a radial gradient should not make any difference. Try all of this in GIMP or read GIMP tutorials. Better still use Photoshop if you can (90 days Trial versions available).

Comment: BTW are you sure gimp cannot save gradients with transparency? A quick look at http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-gradients.html suggests creation is possible. Saving follows as a natural consequence.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite a freshy and don't know what to do with that code to create a .png file from my xml file. GIMP absolutely can save a gradient with transparency. I just don't know what DD and 80 equal as far as percentage of gradient AA (alpha) and how to incorporate 90 degree angle.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no shortcut here. You should be doing some reading. For colors here's a short and sweet primer: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp

Comment: Added some info about colors, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ManishGupta I'm looking for a program that will do this not to achieve it programatically. Thanks for the added info, although I already understand those concepts.

Comment: `Try all of this in GIMP or read GIMP tutorials. Better still use Photoshop if you can (90 days Trial versions available).`

Comment: `**What I'm really looking for is**: a tool and instructions`

Comment: read GIMP tutorials for instructions :) It's been 15 days since your post. You'd have mastered gradients in gimp by now.

Comment: I'm looking for an easier way...ideally plopping my #AARRGGBB start and end into a couple boxes and being able to export a png. I've realized I can do this with ImageMagick and have updated the question. I will be posting my solution shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create an activity with just the gradient as a background, and nothing else on the screen.

Run the app on an emulator or device, and use DDMS to take a screen capture.  You will then have a nicely rendered PNG to save, and you can create whatever size you wish, by varying the screen size of the emulator you are using.

Your XML could look like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/your_gradient">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Booger, unfortunately, that wont preserve the transparency though.